# Why does Cmd-I in Preview do something other than advertised?

Tags: macos, preview, shortcut

Somewhere after Lion (from which I upgraded to 10.10), Apple has changed the shortcut to show/hide the toolbar in Preview from <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> to <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>, at least it says so in the menu entries.
[image] But when actually using the shortcut, what pops up is (as one would expect), the info window. 
[image]

Can someone explain why they would change it (probably not a constructive question), or whether this is a bug and how to rectify this and get the old behaviour back? Can this be done with assigning custom keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *not* a bug, although I can certainly see why it looks like one. That little symbol is a [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar) ( | ), not the letter I. The pipe is the upper character on the backslash ( <kbd>\</kbd> ) key.

So to type <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>|</kbd>, the physical keys you need to press are: <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>.

The difference between "|" and "I" was more pronounced back when Lucida Grande was the system font (in fact, this very post is set in Lucida Grande; you can see how the pipe is taller and thinner than the uppercase I). But OS X Yosemite switched the system font to Helvetica, and unfortunately the "|" and "I" now look basically identical.

Comment: +1 Darn it. I swear I tried it as a pipe and it did not work. But of course it does now. :-O. Think I must have forgot to hold down shift. (tired brain)

Comment: Oh god, so simple! They should've left it on Cmd-B.

Answer (score 0):

As @daGUY spotted it is a pipe "|" symbol.

But you can change it to the old short cuts.or any other that does not clash, by using the keyboard shortcuts in system Preference -> App Shortcuts.

But note: I could not get it to pick up if I assigned new shortcuts to Preview.app (Show Toolbar & Hide Toolbar ).

In the end I assigned the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> for both to `All Applications`  which Preview.app picked up

Comment: It's strange that one has to assign it for both All applications and Preview in particular, any idea why this is?

Comment: @oarfish   No I could not figure that out. For some reason it did not want to know. It could be just my app as I had played with it in the past. Does the same definitely happen for you.

Comment: For me it suffices to set it for All Apps, but for Preview alone is not enough. Weird.

Comment: Would be interesting to know why this was down voted?

Answer (score -1):

This is probably a bug, or you've changed it yourself. Report to Apple and look with them.

You can change this by going to `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Application Shortcuts` and add what you want, you will have to type the exact thing such as "Show Toolbar".

I can't see for myself if it's a mistake on Apples part because I'm using Swedish on my OS X.